# Python: Count the last names with a length of 3 and assign it to the "answer" variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Newbie Python user here.

I have a file, last.txt, from which I am extracting information, that displays the most common last names in the US, alongside their percentage frequency in integer/decimal form. I want to be able to retrieve the number of last names that are three letters long and assign it to the answer variable, but I'm having difficulties. My attempted code is displayed as shown:

```
infile = open('last.txt','r' )
content = infile.read()
wordList = content.split()

count = 0

for i in wordList:
    if i != str:
        count += 0
    elif i == len(3):
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 0
answer = count
print(answer)
```

Whenever I execute the code, I end up with '0', which is incorrect as there are multiple names in the .txt file that are 3 characters long.

The text file I'm using can be downloaded [[here]](http://www.mediafire.com/download/y62devi5v8ci6iu/last.txt).

**EDIT:**

Here are the first several lines of the file linked above. Note that the columns are separated by tabs.

```
SMITH   0.88085
JOHNSON 0.68844
WILLIAMS    0.56866
BROWN   0.51162
JONES   0.50517
MILLER  0.41807
DAVIS   0.39751
GARCIA  0.31817
RODRIGUEZ   0.29813
WILSON  0.29027
MARTINEZ    0.28732
ANDERSON    0.28262
TAYLOR  0.26704
THOMAS  0.26345
HERNANDEZ   0.26185
MOORE   0.259
MARTIN  0.24937
JACKSON 0.24693
THOMPSON    0.23887
WHITE   0.23707
LOPEZ   0.2304
LEE 0.22459
```

Comment: Use `if len(i) == 3`, not `if i == len(3)`.

Comment: Here's a working version of your program (76 bytes, one line): `with open('last.txt','r')as f:print(sum(i==len(3)for i in f.read().split()))`.

Answer (score 1):

Without reproducible data this is hard to do. But first of all, don't use conditional statements if all you're going to do is count += 0 as that is the same as doing nothing. So, instead, do nothing! As well, len(3) should produce an error. An 'int' object has no len()! You should instead do len(i) == 3. So:

```
infile = open('last.txt','r' )
content = infile.read()
wordList = content.split()

count = 0

for i in wordList:
    if len(i) == 3:
        count += 1
answer = count
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
elif len(i) == 3:
```

which will check if the length of `i` is equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition `if i != str:` always evaluates to True, as per the following code prints True:

```
i = "ABC"
print i != str
```

BTW, if you want to test if variables i is a string, use `isinstance(i,str)` but you don't need to do it in your program.

Here is your modified code:

```
infile = open('last.txt','r' )
content = infile.read()
wordList = content.split()
count = 0 
for i in wordList:
  if i == len(3):
    count += 1
print(count)  # this will print how many times a 3-letter word was encountered
```

To get the list of the names, append `answer = []` before entering the `for`loop, then add `if i not in answer: answer.append(i)` after (and at the same level) `count += 1`.  You can also do `print(answer)` after printing the variable `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
infile = open('last.txt','r' )
content = infile.read()
wordList = content.split()

count = 0

for i in wordList:
    if '.' not in i and len(i) == 3:
        count += 1
answer = count
print(answer)
```